# Call overview for ASPX/ASCX pages/controls

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, documentation

I'm working on an ASP.NET project that contains a few hundreds of ASPX/ASCX files, which seem to keep calling each other. And it's a complete mess and it's not clear which page is called from which other page.
And to make it even more complex, this is all used to just generate a single webpage that's "printed to PDF" te generate a report of 20 to 60 pages. So, hundreds of files for one webpage. And I like the concept but now I need to make small adjustments to fix some bugs.
Another complex problem is the fact that these pages don't contain any real text. The report is multi-lingual so each and every line of text is language-dependant and read from a large database containing all texts for each of the 8 languages we support. So, a quick-search for a specific text won't work.
And of course, all documentation could be printed on a piece of paper the size of a stamp. So, no one knows how and where each and every control or page is used.

Well, I want to start creating this documentation first, if it can be done fast and simple. So I'm looking for a tool which can analyse all this code and generate something more human-readable than hundreds of files. A simple Word-document or PDF file would be nice.
Does such a tool exist? Is it free?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just writing a simple console application that walks through all folders and uses regular expressions to find the connections between the many files. It allowed me to collect all class names and solve my problem by dumping data as XML which I then used to create all the practical connections. I've managed to reduce the code from over hundreds of ASCX files to less than 60 files because of the resulting info which I could then refactor into a more practical structure.
It was a lot of work and unfortunately, during work hours. My employer is officially owner of this code so I can't shate it. It's not very nice code either. Just functional enough for a one-shot solution.